# Excel imports numbers with negative exponent incorrectly

Tags: excel

For an analysis I am doing I want to look into my data (space-delimited text file) using Excel, for a better overview. I have some really small numbers in that file (`1.08675e-06`).

Now I am using the Excel import function, select the file and import with delimited with tab + space.

When I look up the same row, the number which was (`1.08675e-06`) in the text file, is `1,09E-01` in the Excel file.

How is  this possible and maybe even more important, how do I make Excel get the right number, instead of the wrong one?

I've already tried changing the "decimal separator" in the "advanced text import settings" in the import settings, which does not seem to work. If someone has an idea, I would love to get some feedback on this problem.

Comment: Just to be clear that there's no typo, you're saying that Excel effectively changes 0.00000108675 to 0.109?

Comment: seems excel is misinterpreting the decimal point, and converting 108675e-06 to 1.09e-01 - check the import settings and make sure that the decimal point character is set correctly for the data you are importing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your Windows Regional settings have the dot as the thousands separator and the comma as the decimal separator.  In Excel, on the Advanced tab of the text import wizard, you need to change both of these -- not just the decimal separator.

[image]

Once you do that, the data should import properly.  But, at least in my version, the cell is formatted with just two decimal places.  However, the formula bar does show the correct value.

[image]

You can easily add decimal places to the formatted number.

An alternative would be to change your Windows Regional Settings with regard to the decimal and thousands separator.

Answer (score 0):

Could you  create a mirror and edit the csv file with notepad and replace dot (.) for comma (,) and try again? The problem appears decimal separator in csv file.